# Is there a way to declare a databound function for kendo grid inside an another grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to resize my grid that inside another grid. These grids are hierarchical. I wrote something for that but this works for second click. The processes I mentioned are seen in the pictures (firstclick, secondclick). the red circle shows extand button.

The js code block I wrote for solution but it does not work properly:

```
// The code inside the databound function of master grid
    $("#SiparisListeleGrid td a.k-icon").click(function () { // onclick for a element that opens second grid inside the row
        if ($(this).hasClass("k-i-expand")) { // if the grid is expand

            // uid of tr element
            var tr_UID = $(this).parents("tr").data("uid");

            // master grid
            var ustGrid = $("#SiparisListeleGrid").data("kendoGrid");

            $(ustGrid.dataSource.data()).each(function (i, item) {
                if (item.uid == tr_UID) {
                    var altGrid = $("#Grid_SiparisSatir_" + item.SipUstID).data("kendoGrid");
                    var rowCount = altGrid.dataSource.view().length;

                    $("#Grid_SiparisSatir_" + item.SipUstID).attr("style", "height:" + (rowCount * 40 + 125) + "px;");

                    $("#Grid_SiparisSatir_" + item.SipUstID + " .k-grid-content").css("height", (rowCount * 40));

                    $("#Grid_SiparisSatir_" + item.SipUstID + " .k-grid-content-locked").css("height", (rowCount * 40));
                }
            });
        }
    });
    // This code block only works on second clicking the expan button.
    // Does not recognize the second grid when clicked for the firs time
    // Should I use databound for second grid? However I do not know how can I do that.
```

[firstclick](https://freeimage.host/i/QP58HG)

[secondclick](https://freeimage.host/i/QP5kSs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code block let me give databound to child grid. It is worked for me.
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfIu7.png)

Comment: Please attach images as an image, not as a file

Comment: Stackoverflow does not let me add an image as an image. It converts to link when I upload the image. Because of that my reputation point.